# Golang reflect: passing a sturct member variable to a function and return its tag name

Tags: go, reflection

```
   type Teacher struct {
     Name string `json:"name"`
     Age int `json:"age"`
   }


   func getTag(i interface{}) string

   getTag(teacher.Name) // print name
   getTag(teacher.Age) // print age
```

I wanna roll my function like the code segment, but I can't find a way to achieve this. Any Ideas?

Comment: The tags are part of the struct type. There's nothing related to the tag in the field value itself.

Answer (score 0):

maybe this can help. https://play.golang.org/p/WtqdQAmsbi

```
x := struct {
    Bar int `json:"bar"`
    Foo string `json:"foo"`

}{2, "foo"}

v := reflect.ValueOf(x)

for i := 0; i < v.NumField(); i++ {
    fmt.Println(v.Type().Field(i).Name)
    fmt.Println(v.Type().Field(i).Tag)
}
```

To fetch the name of the struct field as well as its tag